# Why was the Otsusuki clan genetically compatible with humans to the point they could have children?

Tags: naruto

In the Naruto anime, Kagura Otsutsuki who was an alien "celestial being" could have children with Tenji and they had Hagomoro Otsutsuki. Normally 2 different species can't reproduce unless they have common ancestors. Were the humans and the Otsutsuki aliens related and had common ancestors before they met, was it an amazingly coincidence that they had practicaly they same genes or what? Humans can't reproduce with species who have 99% the same genes so they should have >99% identical to humans, is this ever explained why?

Comment: do you mean kaguya otsutsuki

Comment: tenji is a filler character, as well as that entire arc, it is never canonically specified who the father of hagoromo & hamura are

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [Is it ever acceptable to ask about whether an anime event is realistic or plausible?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/669/1458)

Answer (score 8):

So...this is set in a world where someone who is adept enough can literally generate fire, water, electricity, earth and wind from their hands by weaving specific seals. I'm gonna have to ask that you just *slightly* suspend your disbelief on this one.

There's no explanation as to why this is possible, similar to how there's no explanation as to why *whole* eye transplants have such a high success rate among recipients of the Sharingan or coveted Byakugan (whereas in reality, that just isn't a thing).

Comment: "There's no explanation as to why this is possible" -> Well when two shinobi love each other...

Comment: @Wondercricket:  "When a feudal lord and an alien love each other very much..."